# Can I skip vimscript indentation inside conditional blocks

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I'm editing my `~/.vimrc` this weekend, and I've run into a use case that seems to beg that I strip off indentation in an if-block.

*Broken use-case* in my `~/.vimrc` (with if-block indentation):

```
if has('python3')
  python3 << EOF
# Insert python here
# more python
# and more python
  EOF
endif
```

*Working use-case* in my `~/.vimrc` (without if-block indentation):

```
if has('python3')
python3 << EOF
# Insert python here...
# more python
# and more python
EOF
endif
```

As far as I can tell, the "*Working use-case*" (without indentation) is fine and `vim` seems to have no problems.

If I use the "*Broken use-case*" (with indentation in the vimscript `if` block), vim throws an error that it can't find the terminating `EOF` as well as the `endif` statement.

```
[INFO] Editing '/home/mpenning/.vimrc'.
Error detected while processing /home/mpenning/.vimrc:
line  815:
E990: Missing end marker 'EOF'
  File "<string>", line 4
    EOF
IndentationError: unexpected indent
line  816:
E171: Missing :endif
```

Is there any problem with stripping off indentation inside the `if`-block for my "*Working use-case*"?

Answer (score 1):

In the recent vim (I have 8.2.4975) there is a `trim` parameter and following works for me:

```
if has('python3')
    py3 << trim PYEND
        def hello(world):
            print(world)

        hello("world")
    PYEND
endif
```

I don't know when it was added though.

**UPD** Looks like it is quite old https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/c51cf0329809c7ae946c59d6f56699227efc9d1b/runtime/doc/if_pyth.txt#L779

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem with stripping off indentation inside the if-block for my "Working use-case"?

Indentation is helpful when reading `vimscript`, but indentation is not required.  There is no mention of required indentation for this use-case in the [vimscript documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html).